# Text not being sent in Twisted

Tags: python, client-server, twisted, twisted.internet

I am following official Twisted [examples](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/) about client/server. I am using [LineReceiver.sendLine()](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver.html#sendLine) to send text from client to server. This code works:

```
def connectionMade(self):
    self.sendLine("Hello, world!")
```

and I can see it on my server side. But if I add something like this:

```
def connectionMade(self):
    while self.running:
        command = raw_input(">>")
        if command=="disconnect":
            self.running = False
        else:
            print "sending..."
            self.sendLine(command)
            print "sent."
    self.sendLine("Hello, world!")
```

I can see both '*sending...*' and '*sent*', but nothing more. Server receives nothing even though client appears to be sending the data. If I type '*disconnect*' everything is being sent at once, including '*Hello, world!*'

Hence my question: where does the actual sending takes place? And what to do to achive something like above?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone even if it is duplicate, there is no usable solution given.

Comment: Yes, there is.  Check the accepted answer.  If you don't understand that answer, please comment on it asking what requires clarification.

Answer (score 0):

[LineReceiver](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver.html) has the line-ending delimiter variable. By default it is `'\r\n'`. So the protocol waits until it sees the delimiter before actually writing the data to the socket.

The [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) strips the trailing new line from the input so the protocol never sees the delimiter.

So try sending a new line '\r\n' after the command or append it to the `command` variable.

Comment: this seems reasonable, but unfortunately does not work.